# AngularJS $q promises success callback gets executed in the wrong order

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, deferred

I have a problem with the following code:

```
initPromise = $q.all(arrayOfPromises)
    .then(function () {
        return $scope.methodWhichReturnsPromise()
            .then(function (data) {
                console.log("report data");
                return data;
            });
    });

if ($scope.showCompare) {
    initPromise
        .then(function () {
            return $q.all(anotherArrayOfPromises);
        })
        .then(function () {
            return aMethodWhichReturnsAPromise().then(function () {
                console.log("compare report data");
            });
        });
}

initPromise
    .then(function () {
        console.log("generate view data");
    })
    .finally(function () {
        console.log("finally");
    });
```

I'm loading a bunch of async data when loading a controller based on route parameters. And if the flag `showCompare` is there, I want to load something in between. But the order of the `console.log` messages is the following:

```
report data
generate view data
finally
compare report data
```

I was expecting that `compare report data` would show up exactly in the same order it was written in the code.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are adding two distinct handler on the `initPromise`, instead of chaining all `.then()` calls. To do so, you would need to use

```
if ($scope.showCompare) {
    initPromise = initPromise.then(…);
}
```